# Let $c:|z| = 3$. The value of integral $\int_c\frac{z^2}{z^3-2}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $c:|z| = 3$. Is the value of the integral $\int_c\frac{z^2}{z^3-2}dz$ equal to $0,-πi, πi$ or $2πi$?

Here I see that all the poles lie inside the given circle. So the value of the integral is $0$. Am I right? If not, please help me.

Comment: why does all poles inside the circle imply the integral is 0?

Comment: Ohh, Yes I should calculate Residues on the poles So $\int_cf(z)dz = 2πi$(sum of Residues at Poles)  but I have difficulty to find poles of given function.

Comment: do you know about how to change to coordinates at infinity, using the inversion map $\zeta=\frac{1}{z}$? If yes, then the problem is much simplified. Otherwise, this will be much more computational.

Comment: I don't know such a technique.

Comment: well, I mean it's really just integration by substitution: plug in $z=\frac{1}{\zeta}$, $dz=-\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta^2}$ into your expression, and then the curve $c(t)=3e^{it}$ is replaced by the inverted curve $\gamma(t)=\frac{1}{3e^{it}}=\frac{1}{3}e^{-it}$ (i.e radius $1/3$, traversed in opposite orientation). Anyway, if you still can't do it this way, then calculate where are the three poles of the function (i.e where is the denominator equal to zero). What are the residues there? Add them up.

Comment: Actually I could not calculate roots of $z^3-2 = 0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128088/discussion-between-largest-prime-and-peek-a-boo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The poles must lie *outside* of the circle to apply Cauchy's integral theorem.

Define $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{z^3-2}$. You can calculate the exact value of the integral with the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity):
\begin{eqnarray*} \operatorname{Res}f(z,\infty)
& = &  -\operatorname{Res}_{w=0}\frac{1}{w^2}f\left(\frac{1}{w} \right) \\
& = & -\operatorname{Res}_{w=0}\frac{1}{w^2}\frac{ \frac{1}{w^2}}{\frac{1}{w^3}-2} \\ 
& = & -\operatorname{Res}_{w=0}-\frac{1}{w^4}\frac{w^3}{2w^3-1}\\
& = & -\operatorname{Res}_{w=0}-\frac{1}{w(2w^3-1)}\\
& = & -1.
\end{eqnarray*}

We can conclude $$\int_{z=\lvert 3\rvert}\frac{z^2}{z^3-2}\,\mathrm dz=-2\pi i\operatorname{Res}f(z,\infty)=2\pi i.$$